# Finding newest PayPal API?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm having problems to find the latest API version of PayPal. The current version that I found is 51.0, but it's not the latest version.

I need to add items to the payment summary, and the version has to be >= 53.0.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECCustomizing

Where do I find the latest PHP API examples? (NVP)

Comment: Just check the [Classic API Release Notes](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/release-notes/) to find the current (latest) versions. The most used APIs are summarized as `Merchant API`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference) for PayPal API Reference, scroll a little lower to see your NVP reference.

As I undestood you are trying to customize the Express Checkout, refer [here](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide.pdf) for *PayPal Express Checkout Integration Guide* (PDF).

While technical documentation page [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation).

As I browse on those, it appears it is updated sometime in **April 2012**.

Just use the current PayPal API version. Current version is **89.0**. This seems to be tricky but finding the API version of PayPal is by viewing the source code of the PayPal web page. You'll see a snip in the header like this:

```
<!--
        Script info: script: webscr, cmd: _home, template: xpt/Marketing_CommandDriven/homepage/MainHome, date: May 9, 2012 08:36:29 PDT; country: US, language: en_US, xslt server: 
        web version: 89.0-2920756 branch: UPR_890_int
        content version: -
        pexml version: 89.0-2896586
        page XSL: Marketing_CommandDriven/default/en_US/homepage/MainHome.xsl
       hostname : HuqmOnXTzOtlL7CprWmgAQwFlQK1lZ0z6u5fc-r5fMk
         rlogid : HuqmOnXTzOtlL7CprWmgAYVSw2GbAGynG1%2bkpma0nBQchRCqNea%2ffA%3d%3d_1374663724c
-->
```

`web version: 89.0-2920756` states the API version. Seems not reliable right? I just follow this [thread](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/nvp/latest-paypal-api-version-api-calls) month ago when I did some project requiring PayPal. But hey, it's working.

Comment: Yes, but is there any code examples available?

Comment: You'll see a lot of it in those **PDF**. PayPal just require you to submit a query to their API endpoint. Since you mention NVP I assume you probably or WILL use cURL.

Comment: Of course. But there's still no information about what version I should set. (I just searched the file fast, and I didn't find anything useful) "In most cases, you should use the latest version of the API operation."... What's the latest version?

Comment: Omg... They can't do it easier to find the current version. It was better a few years ago. But big thanks for the answer! ;)

Comment: Same way I thought of months ago. Glad I helped. Cheers! :)

Comment: +'d by a very complete explanation!